# DialogFragment vs Activity with Dialog theme

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I understand that both Dialog-fragment and Activity with Dialog theme can be used to create Dialog in Android. I also understand that both they survive during Orientation changed.

My question is can I always use Activity with Dialog theme for all my dialogs? Is there any case I have to use DialogFragment instead of Activity with dialog theme?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Activity with dialog theme, you can use ActionBar. You can't use ActionBar with Dialog. Android does not provide anyway to add menu/action into Dialog title. You have to implement its yourself.

Dialog is like a Sub-view of Activity so if you use Dialog, you don't have to handle Orientation changed. Communication between Activity and Dialog like a View and Sub-view. This is not true for communication between Activity and Dialog theme-activity.

Choose Dialog Or Dialog themed activity depends your dialog nature/complexity.

Comment: It's absurd to say that there is no need to handle orientation changes for dialogs. Raw dialogs are gone after orientation changes, which is why DialogFragment is recommended, and if that dialog has any states, saving state is required for that too